# I'm not getting drop down list value related forms using panel control

Tags: asp.net

after getting drop down list as output, while selecting the users in drop down list i'm not getting related forms? review the code.i used panel control for 3 user detail tables
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, Eventargs e)
        {

```
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            AdminPanel.Visible = false;
            TeacherPanel.Visible = false;
            StudentPanel.Visible = false;
        }
    }
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "-1")
        {
            AdminPanel.Visible = false;
            TeacherPanel.Visible = false;
            StudentPanel.Visible = false;
        }
        else if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "admin")
        {
            AdminPanel.Visible = true;
            TeacherPanel.Visible = false;
            StudentPanel.Visible = false;
        }
        else if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "teacher")
        {
            AdminPanel.Visible = false;
            TeacherPanel.Visible = true;
            StudentPanel.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            AdminPanel.Visible = false;
            TeacherPanel.Visible = false;
            StudentPanel.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.  Can you describe the problem a bit more?  When you debug this, where/how specifically does it fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question did not provide enough information, but let me take a swing, because it is the common mistake people make regarding DropDownList.

If you want to post back the form to server after selecting the DropDownList, you need to set `AutoPostBack="True"`.

```
<asp:DropDownList 
    ID="DropDownList1" 
    runat="server"
    AutoPostBack="True"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: after modifying Autopostback i'm getting now.